# PhpMyAdmin export does not include PRIMARY KEY as mysqldump

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Export of the struture of the same table with PhpMyAdmin:

```
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_apprentis`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_apprentis` (
  `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL,
  `a_promo_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_cursus` smallint(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Export with mysqldump:

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_apprentis`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `test_apprentis` (
  `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a_promo_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_cursus` smallint(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With PhpMyAdmin, there is no AUTO_INCREMENT nor PRIMARY KEY
Why ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180971/importing-wordpress-database-1075-incorrect-table-definition-there-can-be

Comment: This is not a duplicate of 32180971. That question specifically asks about an error occurring when importing and exporting from Wordpress. The answers are related but the questions are not and someone searching for an answer to this question would not be likely to find that question.

Answer (score 10):

It is not a silly question, phpMyAdmin used to include the KEYs at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement and their characteristics right next to their column name declaration. Following their [2014 changes log](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/history/blob/master/ChangeLogs/ChangeLog-2014), after version 4.2.0.0 (2014-05-08) the export file structure was changed:

- rfe #1004 Create indexes at the end in SQL export

So we must look the end of the exported file to find all the indexes info

Comment: Is there anyway to get keys below create table statement?
first table then keys then second table then key ?

Answer (score 4):

For those that need a solution for this, use the flag `--single-transaction` during `mysqldump`, so it will put `PRIMARY KEY` under `CREATE TABLE` like follows:

`mysqldump --databases mydatabase --single-transaction -u user -p > ./exported_file_name.sql`

Answer (score 2):

I trapped myself as a novice!
I have looked at the contents of the window displayed on the screen, without down vertical lift bar!
Export by phpMyAdmin adds auto-incremented column information and PRIMARY KEY by ALTER TABLE queries after creating the table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_apprentis`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_apprentis` (
  `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL,
  `a_promo_id` smallint(11) NOT NULL,
  `a_cursus` smallint(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3665 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `test_apprentis`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`a_id`);

ALTER TABLE `test_apprentis`
  MODIFY `a_id` smallint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3665;
```

Please accept my apologies for this silly question.

Comment: Its not silly because its causing major havoc with different versions of PMA running on different MYSQL servers.

Comment: I don't understand why it is causing havoc? - it's just moving them to an 'alter' statement - still ends up with same result, no? 
But the PMA team do change things on a whim.

Comment: @anoldermark this yields problems with configurations which require tables to have a primary key.

Comment: I don't understand the solutions here. Isn't the point of using phpMyAdmin (I'm now using 5.1.1) to have IT do all the work without having to edit the export script? I have a db with over 50 tables. Am I supposed to add new lines to every `CREATE TABLE` statement in the export script? That can't be right.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to watch out for in this regard when using export and import is the limit on number of transactions when importing.  There is no warning that the number has been exceeded and the excess have not been executed.  This means that some tables might be present but not have had their Indexes and/or AUTO_INCREMENTS updated particularly when importing whole databases.
Depending on the number of tables and their structure there could be three times that number of transactions required so it would pay to check and adjust the relevant parameter in the php.ini file.

Comment: Your answer was the right one for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert this behavior to how it used to work, edit the file

> phpMyAdmin/libraries/plugins/export/ExportSql.class.php

In the file, the code block starting with the below line needs to be skipped

```
if (preg_match('@CONSTRAINT|KEY@', $create_query)) {
```

The easiest way to do that is changing that line to

```
if (false && preg_match('@CONSTRAINT|KEY@', $create_query)) {
```

Comment: Modifying the core is definitely not the best idea…

Comment: Only if you are, for some reason, scared of open source projects. It's kind of their point. I'm kind of annoyed that others aren't seeing that my answer is the only one that can work.

Comment: That directory and file no longer exist in 5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I manage to add the keys using the custom export method.

[custom export method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAUVG.png)

You have to check the option "Export Metadata" in the "Format-specific options" section.

[format specific options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLR6v.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34784643)