# Why phpmyadmin export produces a syntax error when imported

Tags: phpmyadmin

I exported a Drupal website's database through PhpMyAdmin from my hosting service VPS to my local computer, which works with Fedora 23 workstation. I made a few modifications (through Drupal, not directly on the database) then exported it back from my local computer (PhpMyAdmin 4.5.5.1; 10.0.23-MariaDB) to the VPS (PhpMyAdmin 4.0.10.7;  5.5.42-cll)
and got the following error message:

```
Requête SQL:

--
-- Base de données : `achlaltn_monhuv`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Structure de la table `actions`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
`aid` varchar( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT
);

MySQL a répondu: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 13
```

The original table creation query was:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object that that action acts on (node, user, comment, system or custom types.)',
  `callback` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The callback function that executes when the action runs.',
  `parameters` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parameters to be passed to the callback function.',
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Label of the action.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores action information.';
```

I read that PhpMyAdmin doesn't create the primary key directly, but alter the table later ( [PhpMyAdmin export does not include PRIMARY KEY as mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506556/phpmyadmin-export-does-not-include-primary-key-as-mysqldump) ). But it seems not related to the problem, because the error message is of a **syntax** error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to a recent bug in phpMyAdmin that's been fixed for the current version, 4.6.0. The bug resulted in some problems with importing and exporting tables with comments, and although I haven't seen the exact problem you're seeing chances are very good it was fixed in the current version. I suggest you upgrade from 4.5.5.1 to 4.6.0 and try again.

Fundamentally, the import problem is the `COMMENT` statement without an actual comment following, but you're missing the remainder of the table structure so first try upgrading and see if that fixes the problem.